# Unable to access management console after installing github enterprise

Tags: github, amazon-ec2, github-enterprise

AWS installed github enterprise. The management console is connected during the initial setting, but after saving, infinite loading occurs without errors when attempting to connect. Is there any log that I can doubt or need to check?

I've checked countless reinstallations and logs. The only thing I could check is that SSL handshake error occurs when connecting to the console.

- The installation was installed as an AMI image by following the link below.
  https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.7/admin/installation/setting-up-a-github-enterprise-server-instance/installing-github-enterprise-server-on-aws

Comment: You should support your question with the method you have used to install GitHub enterprise so that it easy where it went wrong